# RxJS Observable emit when previous completes

Tags: rxjs

I have a dynamic array of objects that I need to process synchronously.  I will only know the number of objects in the array at runtime.  Processing each object consists of calling a method that will emit progress notifications as it completes its work.  Processing time for each object will vary considerably (from 30-40 seconds up to ~5 minutes).

*RxJS version 5.5.6*

So basically, I need to:

1. Emit object 1
2. Process object 1
3. Emit object 2
4. Process object 2

(continue for all *n* objects in array).

I don't know how to have the observable wait to emit the next object until the `complete` callback of the previous item has been called.

I've looked at a bunch of operators and the closest I've come is `merge`, but it is still processing all sites at the same time.  Here's where my code stands currently:

In my service:

```
const allObs: Array<Observable<string>> = [];
const siteObserver: Observer<string> = {
  next: (s: string) => console.log(s),
  error: (error: string) => {},
  complete: () => console.log('complete')
};
activeSites.map((site: MatchSite) => {
  const obs: Observable<string> = Observable.create((masterObserver: Observer<string>) => {
    site.process().subscribe((x: string) => console.log(x));
    masterObserver.next(site.tag + ' processing');
  });
  allObs.push(obs);
});
const all: any = Rx.Observable.merge(...allObs);
const sub: Subscription = all.subscribe(siteObserver);
```

In the site object, `process` looks like this (just an interval/timeout simulation for now to try and get this working without the complication of the real processing code):

```
process(): Observable<string> {
    const obs: Observable<string> = Observable.create((observer: Observer<string>) => {
      const int: any = setInterval(() => {
        observer.next('downloading ' + this.tag);
      }, 500);
      setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(int);
        console.log('download done: ' + this.tag);
        observer.complete();
      }, 2000);
    });
    return obs;
  }
```

In a nutshell, I'm seeing this:

```
...
downloading siteA
downloading siteB
downloading siteC
downloading siteD
downloading siteA
downloading siteB
downloading siteC
downloading siteD
...
```

When what I want is this:

```
...
downloading siteA
downloading siteA
downloading siteB
downloading siteB
downloading siteC
downloading siteC
downloading siteD
downloading siteD
...
```

**UPDATE**

When I add a concurrency of 1 to `merge`, or use `concat`, the first site is processed twice and no other sites are processed.  Now I'm really confused...

I can't figure out how `flatMap` would work in this scenario, but am still working on it.

Comment: Use `concat` instead of `merge`. Or specify a `concurrency` of one in the call to `merge` - that's how `concat` is implemented.

Comment: Based on the first paragraph I'd say create a stream based on the array  and use `flatMap`. I find your approach quite confusing, so maybe I'm missing something.